# Unexpected behavior using std::try_to_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

I get surprising and conflicting behavior when I try to run the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(mtx);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(mtx, std::try_to_lock);

    std::cout << "lock1 owns lock: " << lock1.owns_lock() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "lock2 owns lock: " << lock2.owns_lock() << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this on my computer (linux with either clang++ 4.0.1 or g++ 7.3.0) it prints out that both `lock1` and `lock2` own the lock (surprising). When I run this on `cpp.sh` it says that `lock1` does own, but `lock2` does not own the lock (what I expected).

All are using C++11 and `-Wall` without optimizations.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GCC 8.1.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with either version on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yfiu83MMPBQ2ewlA).  Did you use the `-pthread` flag when compiling?

Comment: Can reproduce when not using `-pthread` so I guess you might be missing that?  edit: @NathanOliver beat me to it :D some additional info: it's important to always link with `-pthread` when using threading related things like e.g a mutex. Unforunately there are cases like your where you won't get a linker error but the programm will run what seems to be normally altough it's somewhat undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

As stated in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) for `std::unique_lock` constructor:

> 5. Tries to lock the associated mutex without blocking by calling m.try_lock(). **The behavior is undefined if the current thread already owns the mutex** except when the mutex is recursive.

Emphasis is mine. Since `std::mutex` is not recursive you have undefined behaviour - [`std::mutex::try_lock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock)

> If try_lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

As was answered here, locking mutex that is already owned by the current thread is an undefined behavior according to the C++ standard, but it seems that you know that your implementation is based on POSIX Threads, which has a different set of requirements:

> The `pthread_mutex_trylock()`  function  shall be equivalent to
>   `pthread_mutex_lock()`, except that if the mutex object referenced by
>   mutex is currently locked (**by any thread, including the current
>   thread**), the call shall return immediately.

What you are observing is most likely caused by you not building your code using `-pthread` flag. GNU C++ library detects if program is linked against `libpthread.so` and if it is not, then all calls to `lock`/`unlock` functions are turned into no-op.

You can find some information [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2014-09/msg00148.html):

> `__gthread_mutex_lock` is a one-line function that forwards to `pthread_mutex_lock`. Using GNU libc if you don't link to `libpthread.so`
>   then **`pthread_mutex_lock` is a no-op function that does nothing**. It is
>   quicker to just call it than to spend time checking if threads are
>   active.

Or you can check the source code for `std::mutex::lock` in your header files yourself. You will see something like this:

```
void
lock()
{
  int __e = __gthread_mutex_lock(&_M_mutex);

  // EINVAL, EAGAIN, EBUSY, EINVAL, EDEADLK(may)
  if (__e)
     __throw_system_error(__e);
}

static inline int
__gthread_mutex_lock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
{
  if (__gthread_active_p ())
    return __gthrw_(pthread_mutex_lock) (__mutex);
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Function `__gthread_active_p` will return `0` if `libpthread.so` is not present in the current process, making mutex locking a no-op.

Adding `-pthread` will fix your problem, but you shouldn't rely on this - as demonstrated by your case.